# Infinite Scroll does not show items when displayed with ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

When the Infinite Scroll in [this example](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/MaqMYy) (copied from the Angular Material docs) is shown with the button the items do not appear.

If `ng-show=ctrl.show` is changed to `ng-show=true` the items appear.

Why don't the items appear with ng-show?

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak="" class="virtualRepeatdemoInfiniteScroll" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout="column">
    <p>
       Display an infinitely growing list of items in a viewport of only 7 rows (height=40px).
       <br><br>
       This demo shows scroll and rendering performance gains when using <code>md-virtual-repeat</code>;
       achieved with the dynamic reuse of rows visible in the viewport area. Developers are required to
       explicitly use <code>md-virtual-repeat-container</code> as a wrapping parent container.
       <br><br>
       To enable infinite scroll behavior, developers must pass in a custom instance of
       mdVirtualRepeatModel (see the example's source for more info).
    </p>

    <button ng-click="ctrl.show=!ctrl.show" style="width:100px">Show</button>

    <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container" ng-show=ctrl.show>
      <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.infiniteItems" md-on-demand="" class="repeated-item" flex="">
        {{item}}
      </div>
    </md-virtual-repeat-container>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

    angular
      .module('MyApp')
      .controller('AppCtrl', function($timeout) {

        // In this example, we set up our model using a plain object.
        // Using a class works too. All that matters is that we implement
        // getItemAtIndex and getLength.
        this.infiniteItems = {
          numLoaded_: 0,
          toLoad_: 0,

          // Required.
          getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
            if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
              this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
              return null;
            }

            return index;
          },

          // Required.
          // For infinite scroll behavior, we always return a slightly higher
          // number than the previously loaded items.
          getLength: function() {
            return this.numLoaded_ + 5;
          },

          fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {
            // For demo purposes, we simulate loading more items with a timed
            // promise. In real code, this function would likely contain an
            // $http request.

            if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
              this.toLoad_ += 20;
              $timeout(angular.noop, 300).then(angular.bind(this, function() {
                this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
              }));
            }
          }
        };
      });

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdxjvM

works. Changed ng-show to `style="visibility:hidden/visible"`

I think it has to do with the scrolling distance of the initial list. When it is not visible, there is no height. And this height is computed before the element is visible.